# Only one root element is allowed error on dynamic creation of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```
function AddDivs() {
  var MainDiv = document.createElement('div');
  MainDiv.style.width = "1000px;"
  MainDiv.style.marginTop = "200px;"
  document.getElementById('contentarea').appendChild(MainDiv);
  }
```

"Contentarea" is a div which is already there. I want to add multiple "MainDiv".
My code is executed in the document.ready

I get this "only one root element is allowed" error.

Any clue on this?

This is my html

```
        <div class="container-fluid" id="contentarea">
        <div style="width:1000px;">
            <div id="chart5" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px;"></div>     
            <div id="chart10" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>  
            <div id="chart15" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>  
            <div id="chart16" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>  
        </div>    
        <div style="width:1000px; margin-top:200px;">
            <div id="chartUitval5" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px;"></div>   
            <div id="chartUitval10" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>    
            <div id="chartUitval15" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>    
            <div id="chartUitval16" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>    
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: try this. MainDiv = MainDiv.clone()

Comment: wait can you explain more? where you are using that code? you using other libraries as well?

Comment: I am adding some graph to a page. The page is almost emty.. I want to add rows of graphs (4 graphs next to each other). Inside this maindive I want 4 div's. I do use Jquery in my code as well

Comment: dude need to see more of your codes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did this here and no errors are thrown.

```js
function AddDivs() {
    var MainDiv = document.createElement('div');
    MainDiv.style.width = "1000px;"
    MainDiv.style.marginTop = "200px;"
    document.getElementById('contentarea').appendChild(MainDiv);
 }
 
  AddDivs();
  AddDivs();
  AddDivs();
```

```html
        <div class="container-fluid" id="contentarea">
        <div style="width:1000px;">
            <div id="chart5" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px;"></div>     
            <div id="chart10" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>  
            <div id="chart15" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>  
            <div id="chart16" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>  
        </div>    
        <div style="width:1000px; margin-top:200px;">
            <div id="chartUitval5" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px;"></div>   
            <div id="chartUitval10" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>    
            <div id="chartUitval15" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>    
            <div id="chartUitval16" style="float:left !important; margin-top:10px; margin-left:20px;"></div>    
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: Could it be because I already have two "Maindivs" in the contentarea before my code gets executed the first time?

Comment: No. That should not cause your issue. You should provide you html code as well as any js code related to your issue that you might have left out.

Comment: I added my html but I will try Visile solution first

Comment: I added your html to my answer and still no errors. You can view the output by right clicking on the html side and inspecting the iframe. You will see that the #contentarea div has 3 more div children

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I copy/pasted your answer. That did the trick. Do not know what gave the error in the first place but it is solved now. Everybody thanks for their help

Answer (score 0):

This is procedure , very simply :

```js
function AddDivs(x) {
    var MainDiv = document.createElement('div');
    MainDiv.style.width = "1000px;";
    MainDiv.style.marginTop = "200px;";
    MainDiv.innerHTML = "Hello my id is " + x;
    var id = "injectedDiv" + x;
    MainDiv.setAttribute("id" , id);
    document.getElementById('contentarea').appendChild(MainDiv);
}

$(document).ready(function() { 

  for (var x = 0;x < 10;x++) {
    AddDivs(x);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentarea" style="-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 31px 29px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 31px 29px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 31px 29px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);"  ></div>
```